# Looking to add a function that will terminate the program by typing 'exit'

Tags: python

Right now I have working code that successfully asks the user if they would like to continue on with the program after each input. What I would like to do, however, is instead to allow the user to type the string "exit" at any time to terminate the program. That way I do not need to ask the user after each input and I can instead place a print line at the start letting them know to type "exit" at any time to quit.

```
min_zip = "00001"
max_zip = "99999"

Y = ["YES", "Y"]

def cont_confirm():
    """
    Repeats after every question asking the user
    if they would like to continue or not.
    """
    proceed = input("Do you want to continue with the voter Registration? ")
    if proceed.upper() not in Y:
        print("Exiting program.")
        sys.exit(0)

def main():

    # Loading variables
    f_name = ""
    l_name = ""
    age = oldest_age + 1
    citizen = ""
    state = ""
    zipcode = -1

    # Main body
    print("****************************************************************")
    print("Welcome to the Python Voter Registration Application.")
    cont_confirm()

    # Ensures name is alpha characters
    while not f_name.isalpha():
        f_name = input("What is your first name? ")
    cont_confirm()

    # Ensure name is alpha characters
    while not l_name.isalpha():
        l_name = input("What is your last name? ")
    cont_confirm()

    # Validates within age range 
    while (age < 0 or age > oldest_age):
        print("What is your age? (18-100) ")
        age = float(input())
    if age < 18:
        print("You are not old enough to vote. Exiting program.")
        sys.exit(0)
    cont_confirm()

    # Validates citizen status
    citizen = input("Are you a U.S. Citizen? ")
    if citizen.upper() not in Y:
        print("You are not a U.S. Citizen. Exiting program.")
        sys.exit(0)
    cont_confirm()

    # Validates state residence and ensures the input matches one of the 50 U.S. state codes
    while state not in state_abb:
        state = str.upper(input("What state do you live? (ex. Texas = TX) "))
    cont_confirm()

    # Validates zipcode as a digit and ensures it is within the min/max
    valid_zip = False
    while not valid_zip:
        zipcode = input("What is your zipcode? ")
        if zipcode.isdigit():
            if int(min_zip) <= int(zipcode) <= int(max_zip):
                valid_zip = True

    # Finally, prints all input info and ends.
    print("Thank you for registering to vote. Here is the information we received: ")
    print(f"Name: {f_name} {l_name}")
    print(f"Age: {int(age)}")
    print(f"U.S. citizen: {citizen}")
    print(f"State: {state}")
    print(f"Zipcode: {zipcode}")
    print("Thanks for trying the Voter Registration Application. Your voter",
          "registration card should be shipped within 3 weeks.")
    print("****************************************************************")

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def input_with_exit(message):
    i = input(message)
    if i == "exit":
        exit() # or sys.exit(0)
    else:
        return i
```

And replace all instances of `input` outside of this method with `input_with_exit`.